# Angular: How to make one async function executes first after another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a save function where i need to call another function to get revision num. and there am making api call. since both are async in nature . How to make one function to make wait until other executes

```
$scope.getRevision = function(callback){
    Api.Product.querymyProdById({ prodId: $scope.editProdId }).$promise.then(function(result) {
        if (result && result.length>=1 && result[0].effectiveDate != $scope.editProdmyDate) {
            $scope.editProdRevision = result && result[0].revision +1;
            callback();
        } else {
            $scope.editProdRevision = 100;
        }
    });
}

$scope.saveProd = function(){
     $scope.getRevision(function(){});

     Api.Product.save({
        id: $scope.ProdId;
        revision:$scope.editProdRevision
         -some code

}
```

The above code i wanted to make sure save api should not get called until i get the prodRevision.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Return promises and chain them. If you return a promise in a .then it will wait for it to resolve before continuing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have promises do not mess with callbacks. Make your functions actually return a promise and use `then` to chain calls.

```
$scope.getRevision = function(){
    return Api.Product.querymyProdById(..).$promise...;
}

$scope.saveProd = function() {
   return $scope.getRevision().then(function() {
        return Api.Product.save(...);
   })
}
```

Comment: Agree, Api.Product.querymyProdById should return a promise aswell, if you are using $http or so you can directly return this one or create a custom promise with $q.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what javascript gods invented callbacks for

```
$scope.saveProd = function(){
     $scope.getRevision(function(){
        // this happens after getRevision finished
        Api.Product.save({
           id: $scope.ProdId;
           revision:$scope.editProdRevision
            -saome code
        });
     });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple make one async call after the other, like this -

```
// First Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
  // Second Simple GET request example:
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/someUrl'
   })
   .then(function successCallback(response) {

   }, function errorCallback(response) {

   });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: If you return the second `$http` it will flatten out the chain. Means you can register a second `.then` on the higher level which will wait for both AJAX requests to complete. Promises shouldn't be thought of and used like nested callbacks.

Comment: @ste2425 can you please explain with an example please or a link to some resource that I can read up? Thanks!

Comment: Heres a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9PMf9TZn) of your example. And a [blog post](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/) that may help. Promises are brilliant things but are a whole other way of working vs callbacks. You can get really neat and concise data flows with them. You can nest them like you did (useful for complex chains) but this use case didn't call for it. Flattening the chain would have exactly the same effect and be more readable.

Comment: @ste2425 thanks for the links and you know I always smelt something fishy  using them in this manner... Code smells bad now but hay, better late than never! :D